# how to find Jsp (.java)file in eclipse

Tags: jsp

I am creating a simple jsp file,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
<title>Insert title here</title>
 </head> 
<body> 
<center>
 <font color="gray" size="7"> Hello World! </font>
 </center>
 </body>
 </html>
```

but
I tried manually compile the jsp and depoly in server,but i am unable to see the jsp (.java) file.
How can i find the jsp compiler generated (.java)file in manually and ide's. I can i see the server generated file.In manual process where can i see that file ...please solve this problem.

Comment: It'll be in the project's Eclipse workspace.

Comment: where exact it will stored plz tell me.

Comment: Can't you just search for recent java files in your project's workspace?

Comment: "How can i find the jsp compiler generated (.java)file in manually and ide's." Compiling a jsp file doesnt produce a .java file... if your having trouble seeing it when your deploying to a server vs your ide, then you should check that you configured your web.xml properly

Comment: I want internal code of jsp compiler generated(.java) file.How can i see that file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **.java** file is internally created the server.

if you want more about this please go through the Java Server Pages documentation.its clearly given how this Java Server Pages works.